# Unix - BASH- Grep User variables, pipe matched results to a new file

Tags: bash, variables, unix, grep

```
echo "Please enter the names of the users you wish to search for on the same line."
echo "Press enter when finished."
read -p "Enter four names now: " vara varb varc vard
egrep "$vara|$varb|$varc|$vard" payroll.txt > newpayroll.txt
```

So, my questions are;

1) Is there any more efficient way of collecting the names? The instructions specify they have to be on one line, which is why I used read as opposed to a loop.

2) Once I have my file, despite my best efforts to use something like

```
tr -s '[[:punct:][:space:]]' '\n' < names.txt > newnames.txt
```

To rearrange it back into column form, the payroll file looks like

```
Sally:F:22:15
Mike:M:24:16
```

Instead of going one after the other.

So in short, the plan is to get the matched names from the user, find it within this file, save these results in a new file (this is where it looks like it's going)
then make it suitable for cutting (which is what I need to do next)

Using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)

Comment: Hm, this looks a lot like ... a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Untested

```
read -p "Enter usernames, space separated: " -ra names
grep -Ff <(print "%s\n" "${names[@]}") names.txt > newnames.txt
```

You could use `awk` in place of `grep`, more verbose, but more accurate: we're testing string equality only for the first field, not a regex on the whole line.

```
awk -F: -v namestring="${names[*]}" '
    BEGIN {
        n = split(namestring, nm, " ")
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) names[nm[i]] = 1
    }
    $1 in names
' names.txt > newnames.txt
```

Comment: The second line appears not to work, but obviously, I'm not going to down vote you. If I wanted to ask a follow up question (I just went ahead and did it my way, and for some reason, it worked) about cutting, would I ask another question?

Comment: This can be done without bashisms. `read -p "Enter usernames, space separated: " names; for n in $names; do echo "^$n:"; done |grep -f- /etc/passwd` (/etc/passwd has the same general formatting, so I easily could test my code). This uses exact matches only, which seems to be what the questioner wants.

Comment: Yes, that's simpler. `printf "^%s\n" $names` can replace the for-loop.